# Semantic UI React transition issue on multiple divs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am having a scoping issue with Semantic UI React transitions. My issue is that transitions work fine but when I click one of the divs... ALL of them animate. I only want one of them to animate.

My code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { animation: 'pulse', duration: 1000, visible: true }
  toggleVisibility = () => this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible })
  render() {
    const { animation, duration, visible } = this.state
    return (
      <Container>
        <Transition animation={animation} duration={duration} visible={visible}>
              <div className="card" content='Run' onClick={this.toggleVisibility}>
                Testing
              </div>
            </Transition>
        <Transition animation={animation} duration={duration} visible={visible}>
              <div className="card" content='Run' onClick={this.toggleVisibility}>
                Testing
              </div>
            </Transition>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PEXgyg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're giving the same `visible` value to both `Transition` elements at the same time. You need to refactor to something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  //Please don't use visible1 and visible2 as names!
  state = { animation: 'pulse', duration: 1000, visible1: true, visible2:

  toggleVisibility = (prop) => () => this.setState(state => ({ [prop]: !state[prop] }))

  render() {
    const { animation, duration, visible1, visible2 } = this.state
    return (
      <Container>
        <Transition animation={animation} duration={duration} visible={visible1}>
              <div className="card" content='Run' onClick={this.toggleVisibility("visible1")}>
                Testing
              </div>
            </Transition>
        <Transition animation={animation} duration={duration} visible={visible2}>
              <div className="card" content='Run' onClick={this.toggleVisibility("visible2")}>
                Testing
              </div>
            </Transition>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

I changed setState to its functional form because you're using the previous state to calculate the next one.

Since onClick takes a callback, I made `toggleVisibility` a curried function: it takes a prop name and returns a function which will be called on the click event. I'm also using an ES2015 feature called "computed property names" on `[prop]: !state[prop]`

Comment: That works! Thank you. Can you explain: `toggleVisibility = (prop) => () => this.setState(state => ({ [prop]: !state[prop] }))` or link me where it can be explained

Comment: Done, I hope that makes it clearer. You can google "functional setState" and "computed property names on es6" for more info